# vs 2010 installation after vs 2012 , cant see vs 2010 run option

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

i want to use vs 2010 and 2012 side by side on my single windows instance. I had vs 2012 installed and created a project in it, now I install vs 2010 and tried to run it but their is no run option for it, there are many options like configure, info etc but no run option ,it showed that vs 2010 was successfully installed, there were no errors at that time while installing ,,,, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this file directory and run this EXE and VS2010 should start for you if you had no install errors. I have both running just fine on my single windows instance.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Comment: Now that you have 2010 running, I'd recommend re-running the VS2012 installer and doing a "repair", which will ensure that the VS2010 install has not overwritten anything that VS2012 needs with an older version.

Comment: :( its not actually running, its showing a messagebox indicating "Only some of the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Products On this computer have been upgraded to service pack 1, none will work correctly until all have been upgraded. I repaired the vs 2010 but again this message is appearing

Comment: Can you use windows update and make sure everything is on service pack 1?